# Error message "external table is not in the expected format" when I tried to upload file in C# program

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview, oledb, dataadapter

I am creating a C# program where I can browse and view the file into a datagridview in C#. I've been tested it for so many times and it worked well. But yesterday when I tried to do it again an error messaged displayed stating "**Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;**". The file that I am testing is the same file that I used before(with no errors). I didn't do anything with the file(excel file).

This is the print screen of the error message:
[image]

This is the code I used:

```
 private void buttonUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string OleDBConnection = String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;""", textBoxFileName.Text);

        string query = String.Format("select * from [{0}$]", "Sheet1");

        OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, OleDBConnection);

        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

        dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];

    }
```

Comment: Please read the words of the error message. "External table is not in the expected format" is very clear - you're telling the data provider to expect a file of a certain format (`Excel 8.0`) in your connection string, and the file you're opening is not in the proper format, probably because the file you have in `textBoxFileName.Text` isn't a supported file. There is absolutely no information in your question to be of any more help than that - check the file you're passing in `textBoxFileName.Text`.

Answer (score 2):

```
 If Path.GetExtension(pth).ToLower().Equals(".xls") Then
     strcon = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & pth & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;"""
 Else
     strcon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & pth & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;"""
 End If
```